# Access 2013 - Subform Does Not Immediately Update with New Parent Form Information

Tags: ms-access

Using Access 2013, I have a parent form for entering customer transactions.

I have a subform that lists the history of all transactions.
When I enter, and save, a new transaction, the subform does not immediately update to include the new transaction.
But when I close and reopen the form, I can see the new transaction in the subform.

Is there a way to make the subform update immediately to include the new transaction as soon as the new transaction as saved?
This would be great for user feedback/confirmation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

## Edit

sorry I miss read your question. What you need is **Form.Requery**. This will displays any new or changed records or removes deleted records from the table on which the form or control is based. You can place this into your save button like so:

`Private Sub Command0_Click()
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
    Form.Requery
    End Sub`

For more information regarding Requery check out:

[Requery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff191903.aspx)